# I don't know why the copy constructor's call is erratic in c++

Tags: c++, constructor, copy, move

I studied to understand the concept of Move, and I wrote code to see the copy constructor invocation differences.

But it's embarrassing that the copy constructor's call is erratic.
I can't understand why it was printed like this.

Below is a simple example code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class A {
private:
    string s;

public:
    A(string s) : s(s) {}

    A(const A& ref) {
        s = ref.s;
        cout << s << " copy constructor" << endl;
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const A&);
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const A& pos) {
    os << pos.s << endl;
    return os;
}

int main(void) {

    vector<A> v;

    v.push_back(A("a"));
    v.push_back(A("b"));
    v.shrink_to_fit();

    cout << &v[0] << " v.capacity() : " << v.capacity() << endl;

    v.push_back(A("c"));
    v.push_back(A("d"));

    cout << &v[0] << " v.capacity() : " << v.capacity() << endl;
    cout << v[0] << v[1] << v[2] << v[3] << endl;

    cout << "///////////////////////////////////" << endl;

    vector<A> v2;

    v2.emplace_back(("a"));
    v2.emplace_back(("b"));
    v2.shrink_to_fit();

    cout << &v2[0] << " v.capacity() : " << v2.capacity() << endl;

    v2.emplace_back(("c"));
    v2.emplace_back(("d"));

    cout << &v2[0] << " v.capacity() : " << v2.capacity() << endl;
    cout << v2[0] << v2[1] << v2[2] << v2[3] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

output :

```
a copy constructor
b copy constructor
a copy constructor
0073A578 v.capacity() : 2
c copy constructor
a copy constructor
b copy constructor
d copy constructor
a copy constructor
b copy constructor
c copy constructor
0073EFF0 v.capacity() : 4
a
b
c
d

///////////////////////////////////
a copy constructor
0073A578 v.capacity() : 2
a copy constructor
b copy constructor
a copy constructor
b copy constructor
c copy constructor
0073E970 v.capacity() : 4
a
b
c
d
```

I don't know why the copy constructor call is erratic.

so.

```
v.push_back(A("a"));
v.push_back(A("b"));
v.shrink_to_fit();

cout << &v[0] << " v.capacity() : " << v.capacity() << endl;
```

My expected output for this part is:

```
a copy constructor
b copy constructor
009A6CA8 v.capacity() : 2
```

But the output is different.

```
a copy constructor
b copy constructor
a copy constructor
009A6CA8 v.capacity() : 2
```

I don't know why I called 'a' one more time in this part.

The same is true for others. Some are duplicated and some are not.

I want to see the difference between a copy constructor and a move call. Is the code wrong?

Comment: For the example shown, you don't need a copy-constructor. If there's no copy-constructor the compiler will auto-generate one for you which will do the right thing. Also note that copy-construction might be *elided* (i.e. compiler will do an in-place construction without calling the copy-constructor).

Comment: And can you please try to elaborate on what you think is weird or "erratic" with the shown output? Can you point out some specifics?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude 
Explained. I hope to see you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the output

```
a copy constructor
b copy constructor
a copy constructor
009A6CA8 v.capacity() : 2
```

the first `a copy constructor` comes from when `A(a)` is copied into the vector.

The second `a copy constructor` is because of the vector *resizing*. When you push the second element, the vector will be resized which could include allocating new memory and copying the old elements into the new memory.

Try printing the `capacity` before the first `push_back` and *between* the first and second `push_back` (without any `shrink_to_fit`). You will see the capacity go from `0` to `1` to `2`. Each increase in capacity is a new allocation and which will copy all existing elements (but from `0` to `1` there's no elements in the vector, so nothing is copied).

Comment: Resizing would _move_ the elements, if possible. But the class lacks a move constructor.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to study the move constructor, you have to provide one. A class with a user-provide copy-constructor (like yours) does not have a move constructor, and therefore will not be moved. Hence, it will be copied in places where it otherwise could be moved.

Comment: Does `emplace_back ()` also copy if there is no move constructor?

Comment: `emplace_back` will construct in place. But if a reallocation is needed to provide space at the back, that reallocation will move or copy existing objects first.